# Match "df['items']" values with "df1" columns & if values match, store matched value in new dataframe "out", so the expected o/p as below

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have tried this below code, values matched but result stored under same column i.e, `items`. I converted `df1` columns into variables and match with `df`. But I want result in new dataframe `out`:

```
for ticker in tickers:
 dfs = df1[df1["ticker"] == ticker]
 asset = str(int(dfs['asset'].values[0]))
 debt = str(int(dfs['debt'].values[0]))
 debtc = str(int(dfs['debtc'].values[0]))
 
 data = [ticker, asset, debt, debtc]
 def checkIfValuesExists1(df, ticker):
  for ele in ticker:
   if ele in df['items'].values:
    out[ele] = data      
   return out
 out = checkIfValuesExists1(df, data)
```

My current output is:

`out`:

| ticker | items |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 |
| MSFT | 7778 |
| GOOGL | 7654 |

`df`:

| ticker | items |
| --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 |
| MSFT | 7778 |
| GOOGL | 7654 |

`df1`:

| ticker | asset | debt | debtc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 | 9674 | 9755 |
| MSFT | 4477 | 7778 | 6545 |
| GOOGL | 5675 | 5535 | 7654 |

Expected output i.e, `out`:

| ticker | asset | debt | debtc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 4564 |  |  |
| MSFT |  | 7778 |  |
| GOOGL |  |  | 7654 |

Answer (score 0):

Use `eq` to identify value equality in a vectorised way and use `where` to mask NaN values.

```
df = pd.Series([4564, 7778, 7654], index=["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOGL"])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "asset": [4564, 4477, 5675],
        "debt": [9674, 7778, 5535],
        "debtc": [9755, 6545, 7654],
    },
    index=["AAPL", "MSFT", "GOOGL"],
)


df1.where(df1.eq(df, axis=0))
```